# Status bar is hidden under fullscreen but it shows up when menu key pressed in Android

Tags: android, menu, statusbar, android-fullscreen

I have an App containing a toggle FullScreen function.
It did success to toggle fullscreen using the following code.

```
    if (tofull) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            Log.i("toggleFullScreen", "API<16");
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            Log.i("toggleFullScreen", "API>=16");
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            // Hide the status bar.
            // int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }

    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            Log.i("toggleFullScreen", "API<16");
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            Log.i("toggleFullScreen", "API>=16");
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            // Hide the status bar.
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }
```

It can hide status bar after toggled to fullscreen mode.

However, when I pressed **hardware menu key** button (I have an options menu which will show up after menu key pressed), the **status bar comes out**. And status bar **does not hide again**.

What will be the possible reason for this problem exists?
Could anyone solve it(make the status bar hide again automatically)?

Answer (score 0):

That because the flags are been cleared and you need to call your full screen function again.

please read this article .
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Note that this only from api 19.

Answer (score 0):

Please override this method on your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        Log.d(TAG,"did pressed menu button");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

so this way you can avoid menu is shown when you app is on full-screen mode.